# c# $ string in resource

Tags: c#, .net, resources, c#-6.0

I need to add `$"test message {variable1} and {variable2}"` kind of string into the resource file.
Earlier this can be done using the string builder format like below

```
test message {0} and {1}
```

Let me know is there any alternative for doing this for $ string format

Comment: From what I know there's no such possibility. You can still use a format `test message {0} and {1}` with your `variable1` and `variable2`

Comment: $ strings are just sugar around format strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$"test message {variable1} and {variable2}"` is syntactic sugar for `string.Format("test message {0} and {1}", variable1, variable2)`.

You can only put static values in resources. You can't put dynamic values as a formatted string from dynamic values.

If you REALLY want to use string interpolation for this, you need to key your resources with the formats and do something like this:

```
string R(FormattableString fs)
{
    return string.Format(Resources.GetString(fs.Format), fs.GetArguments());
}

// uses "test message {0} and {1}" as resource key
R($"test message {variable1} and {variable2}");
```